# Handling Multiple Javascript Files with Logic Structure

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if this is a relevant programming question for this site, or if it belongs elsewhere, but I'll ask anyways.

Currently I am working with a javascript file that has a structure that looks like this, I came up with in on my own and was super proud when I did

```
$(function(){
    var dir = document.URL;

    if(dir.indexOf('contact') > -1){
         // do stuff in here for contact/index.php...
    }else if(dir.indexOf('about') > -1){
         // do stuff in here for about/index.php...
    }else{
         // everything for the index page goes here
   }
});
```

It is a very elegant and beautiful code set up and I love it. However, I build large admin dashboards for a living, and I have found that the file can get very extensive, like 3000+ plus lines long. While I know this is not an unusual thing it is a literal pain in the butt to figure out where some things are some days. Is there some kind of `include` function for javascript that would help me organize this?

**other issues involving this structure**

It has been brought to my attention that there is an error in my logic structure and now I have work around that too.

It was pointed out that what happens when my URL looks like the following:

`http://...index.php?contact=1`

Then logically I would be running the wrong code, how do I get around this?

**research results**

So far I've found some things where they say you can do a $.get call on another js file, but that seems highly inefficient to me.

Does `document.write` do anything for me here?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a flippant scenario: what happens when your site grows to include something like `/about/index.php?tab=contact` - with this logic you'll be running the wrong code.

Comment: yeah I've considered that, and while I have not run into any instances, you have a point